# Trying to only allow 1 image to drop into a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

hello I have been trying to find a way to do this for days and I have searched unsuccessfully. I have four images and four divs to drop them in. The hard part is that I only want the user to be able to drop each image in only the respective div, and not be able to drop them in multiple places. This way only the first image can be dropped into the first box, the second into the second and so forth. I don't know any jQuery, and would strongly prefer to use javascript as simply as possible. Thanks!!

HTML:

```
<div class="inventory">
    <p id="inventory">Inventory
    <div class= "tooltip"> 
        <img id="normalChest" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="chest.png" height = "25" width = "25" draggable = "true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
        <span class= "tooltiptextnormal">Normal Chest</span>
    </div>
    <div class= "tooltip">
        <img id="uncommonChest" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="SilverChest.png" height = "25" width = "25" draggable = "true" >
        <span class= "tooltiptextuncommon">Uncommon Chest</span>
    </div>
    <div class= "tooltip">
        <img id="rareChest" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="PlatinumChest.png" height = "25" width = "25" draggable = "true" >
        <span class= "tooltiptextrare">Rare Chest</span>
    </div>
    <div class= "tooltip">
        <img id="exoticChest" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="GoldChest.png" height = "25" width = "25" draggable = "true" >
        <span class= "tooltiptextexotic">Exotic Chest</span>
    </div>
    </p>
    <script src="game.js">
    document.getElementById("inventory").innerHTML = inventory;
    </script>

</div>


<div class="chestOpenerCommon"  id="div1"  ondragover="allowDropCommon(event)">
    <h4>Open your Common chests here!</h4>
</div>
<div class="chestOpenerUncommon"  id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDropUncommon(event)">
    <h4>Open your Uncommon chests here!</h4>
</div>
<div class="chestOpenerRare"  id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDropRare(event)">
    <h4>Open your Rare chests here!</h4>
</div>
<div class="chestOpenerExotic"  id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDropExotic(event)">
    <h4>Open your Exotic chests here!</h4>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function allowDropCommon(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
accept: '#normalChest';
};
function allowDropUncommon(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
accept: '#uncommonChest';
};
function allowDropRare(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
accept: '#rareChest';
};
function allowDropExotic(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
accept: '#exoticChest';
};
function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data =
ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
randomNormalItem = normal[Math.floor(Math.random()*normal.length)];
inventory.push(randomNormalItem);
alert(inventory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logic to the `drop` function to check if the image you are dropping corresponds to correct chest. I don't think you need those `allowDropXXX` functions.

I've created a jsfiddle based on your example code (replaced chest with cute cats): https://jsfiddle.net/ruh910b6/2/

Comment: after running this code, even in JSFiddle, it didn't seem to be working correctly. Unfortunately when a user would drag the picture over the space it was intended for (or any space for that matter) it was not allowed to drop. I did get a better understanding though so thank you for that!